# Loading last record of hasMany relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-6

I have the following code in my controller where I am trying to load all 'members'. Every member can have more than one phone number. Phone numbers are stored in a table called `phone_numbers` and are tied to user id's. Below, I am trying to load the last phone number stored for every member. Note, the user has a hasMany relationship on the phone.

User.php

```
public function phone()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Model\PhoneNumber');
}
```

This is what I tried:

```
$members = \App\Model\User::all();
$members->load('phone');
```

I appreciate any suggestions on how to accomplish this.

Comment: What do you mean by last phone number?

Comment: Every user can have more than one phone number. I mean, i want the newest phone number tied to every user.

Comment: Do you use the Laravel's timestamp attributes in your table (`created_at` and `updated_at`)?

Comment: Yes, I did, I have that set up

Answer (score 32, accepted):

To get the latest row, you can just use `latest`, and use `hasOne` relationship like this:

```php
public function phone()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Model\PhoneNumber')->latest();
}
```

So you can get the latest phone for all users:

```php
User::with('phone')->get();
```

Comment: You should mention that `with('phone')` before retrieving models is important because of relationship's lazy loading. (I forgot it in my answer)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This is clean. Will this also get users without a phone number stored?

Comment: Wait, this doesn't work. Note, phone is **hasMany** relationship.

Comment: @AnchovyLegend yes, if you want to get without phone number, you can use `whereHas` method. You can define `hasMany phones` and `hasOne phone`

Comment: No, I want it to include all users with and without phone numbers and get the phone numbers when available. So I can then do `$mebmers->phone_number` to get the latest phone number in my view.

Comment: @Shizzen83 In fact, the post `load()` is eager-loading too.

Comment: @TsaiKoga, what do you mean I can have `hasMany phones` and `hasOne phone` ?

Comment: @AnchovyLegend You can defined two relationship. One is `hasMany phones` which can load all phones for u. Another relationship  `hasOne phone`, which can load the latest phone for u. And you can use one of them if you need it.

Comment: I don't understand how I would do that. I would have two separate phone relationship functions in my User entity?

Comment: @AnchovyLegend Yes. Use diff method name. Laravel will convert the diff relationship's methods to the corresponding raw sql. Get the diff results.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210939/discussion-between-anchovylegend-and-tsaikoga).

Answer (score -2):

You could achieve this by doing:

in your User model:

```php
/**
     * The accessors to append to the model's array form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $appends = ['last_phone'];


protected function getLastPhoneAttribute()
{
    return $this->phone()->orderBy('created_at')->first();
}
```

```php
use App\Model\User;

$lastPhones = User::all()->map->last_phone;
```

Comment: What I want to add it to my members data that I am going to inject? so I can do `$member->phone_numeber`?

Comment: Note, this doesn't work. I set $appends to the actual field name of the phone number i.e. `phone_number` and in my controller I did this: `$members = User::all()->map->phone_number;
        dd($members);`

All phone numbers are coming back `null`.

Comment: Be careful about accessor, this mean every query to this User model, it will all load the phones

Comment: `last_phone` is a virtual attribute, the `$appends` property tells Laravel to append it on every model.

Comment: Okay, what is the purpose of `getLastPhoneAttribute`? how does `map` know what to do?

Comment: You have everything explained here https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-mutators for the attribute and here for the `map` https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#higher-order-messages

Comment: Like @TsaiKoga said, notice that use `-attribute()` (accessor) will produce database query every time. If you use this expression within iteration, it will cause performance issue like N+1 query. Better use `with()` (eager loading) instead.